# python word2vec context similarity using surrounding words

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I would like to use embeddings made by w2v in order to obtain the most likely substitute words GIVEN a context (surrounding words), rather than supplying an individual word.

Example:
sentence = 'I would like to go to the park tomorrow after school'

If I want to find candidates similar to "park", typically I would just leverage the similarity function from the Gensim model

```
model.most_similar('park')
```

and obtain semantically similar words. However this could give me similar words to the verb 'park' instead of the noun 'park', which I was after.

Is there any way to query the model and give it surrounding words as context to provide better candidates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word2vec is not, primarily, a word-prediction algorithm. Internally it tries to do semi-predictions, to train its word-vectors, but usually these training-predictions aren't the end-use for which word-vectors are wanted.

That said, recent versions of gensim added a `predict_output_word()` method that (for some model modes) approximates the predictions done during training. It might be useful for your purposes.

Alternatively, checking for the words `most_similar()` to your initial target word that are *also* somewhat-similar to the context words might help.

There have been some research papers about ways to disambiguate multiple word senses (like 'to /park/ a car' versus 'walk in a /park/') during word-vector training, but I haven't seen them implemented in open source libraries.